# Mobile Application parse login results

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, parsing

I am currently trying to complete a mobile application login and I'm running to a problem parsing the success function of my ajax. Any help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //event handler for submit button
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            //collect userName and password entered by users
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            //call the authenticate function
            authenticate(username, password);
        });
    });
//authenticate function to make ajax call
function authenticate(username, password) {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
        url: "http://my-domain.com/php/jsonserver.php?func=Login",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        //json object to sent to the authentication url
        data: '{"username"="' + username + '", "password"="' + password + '"}',
        success: function () {
            //do any process for successful authentication here


            }
    })
}
```

Comment: I know that i need to parse the result in the success function but not sure where to start. Also need to then store the session id in a cookie before going to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.

This is what i ended up using:

```
function authenticate(username, password) {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL+"func=Login",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,

        data: {username:username,password:password},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 

                if(data.Result.ErrCode==null)
                {
                    $('.session').html(data.Result.Data[0].sessionid);
                    $('.username').html(data.Result.Data[0].shortname);
                    SESSIONID = (data.Result.Data[0].sessionid);
                    $.mobile.changePage('#main');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#error').html(data.Result.ErrMsg);

                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error');

            }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand your problem exactly but I think you are dealing with problem in parsing status from web service. Hope the following code helps.

```
function checkPin(){
        var uname=document.getElementById("uname").value;
        var password= document.getElementById("pintxt").value;

        $.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          url:"http://hostname/folder/login.php?callback=jsondata&UserName="+uname+"&Password="+password,
          crossDomain:true,
          dataType:'jsonp',
          success: function jsondata(data)
               {
                    var parsedata=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                var logindata=parsedata["Status"];

                if("status"==logindata)
                {
                    alert("success");
                    window.open("user.html","_self");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Login failed");
                    document.getElementById("pintxt").value="";
                    pintxt.focus();
                }
              }  
        }); 
    }
```